# How to restrict VBA code to a specific worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to restrict the macro to a specific the Test! worksheet When I activate the macro pasted below and I am within the Test! worksheet, the macro works. However, when I try activating the macro on a different sheet, I receive an error. Any idea on what I need to do to modify the VBA code in order for it to be work any other worksheet within the workbook? Thanks

```
Sub Test ()
' Test Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+B
'
  Range ("Test!B1").Select 
  Selection.ClearContents
  Range ("Test!B2").Select
  Selection.ClearContents
  Range ("Test!B3").Select
  Selection.ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: The above code will not compile so I doubt it works. What is the exact code please that has been running for you.

Answer (score 5):

You must reference the worksheet directly:

```
Dim ws as worksheet
set ws = Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Test")

with ws
  .Range("B1:B3").ClearContents  
end with
```

Other notes: 
Don't use `.Select` or `Selection`. Simply operate on the objects directly.
You have String issues in your original code that would cause compile-time errors (fixed in my code)
You can clear the entire range in one line of code, rather than cell by cell

Comment: You should use the `Worksheets` collection to retrieve a `Worksheet` instance. `Sheets` contains all sheet types, including non-worksheet sheets (e.g. `Chart`) - if the user renames the "Test" sheet, and adds a `Chart` sheet that they name "Test", this code will throw a type mismatch error. If the "Test" sheet is renamed to anything else, this code will throw a *subscript out of range* error. Use the sheet's codename identifier for a more robust solution that won't break unless the sheet is outright deleted.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon fair point I'll update the answer to use the more specific Worksheets collection of the workbook

Answer (score 3):

If the worksheet exists at compile-time in `ThisWorkbook` (i.e. the same file that's hosting the VBA code), then you don't need to retrieve the sheet at all - not by name, not by index.

VBA is already declaring a global `Worksheet` object variable for that sheet (and every sheet in `ThisWorkbook`). Verify the sheet's `(Name)` property; change it to `TestSheet`, then you can use `TestSheet` as an identifier anywhere in your code to refer to that sheet.

```
TestSheet.Range("B1:B3").ClearContents
```

And this code will work regardless of whether the user moved the sheet to another index/position in the workbook, or whether the user renamed the sheet's "tab" to something else.

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B1:B3").ClearContents ' breaks if sheet is moved
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test").Range("B1:B3").ClearContents ' breaks if sheet/tab is renamed
```

Comment: You don't see the worksheet's Codename being used much anymore. Good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

## The Basics

If you want to learn something you should study versions 1 and 2, which are elaborate versions of versions 3 and 4 respectively.

Use Option Explicit to quickly find mistakes.
Use constants to be able to quickly change values.
Use object references to not have to type names on and on.

It is assumed that you will copy these codes in any module in the workbook where the worksheet 'Test' resides.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test1()

  Const cStrWs As String = "Test" 'Worksheet Name
  Const cStrRng As String = "B1:B3" 'Range to 'DEL'

  Dim oWs As Worksheet 'Worksheet Object
  Dim oRng As Range 'Range Object

  Set oWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWs) 'Create a reference to the worksheet
  Set oRng = oWs.Range(cStrRng) 'Create a reference to the range

  oRng.ClearContents

End Sub

Sub Test2()

  Const cStrWs As String = "Test" 'Worksheet Name
  Const cStrCell As String = "B1" 'Cell to 'DEL'
  Const cLngCells As Long = 3 'Number of cells

  Dim oWs As Worksheet 'Worksheet Object
  Dim oRng As Range 'Range Object

  Set oWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWs) 'Create a reference to the worksheet
  Set oRng = oWs.Range(cStrCell) 'Create a reference to the cell range

  oRng.Resize(3, 1).ClearContents

End Sub

Sub Test3()
  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test").Range("B1:B3").ClearContents
End Sub

Sub Test4()
  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test").Range("B1").Resize(3, 1).ClearContents
End Sub
```